# EntityFramework updating .edmx not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I made some changes to a table column [A] on my sql database, and tried to "update model from database" in visual studio, but I did not see the changes.  I tried to rebuild, but still no changes.  I then deleted the column [A] that was not updated from the .edmx [diagram] and update model from database again, but still no changes.

How can I get the changes to show now?

Comment: Delete the table and add again from edmx.

Comment: Yes, that works, I was going to do that, but what if the table had relationships with another table?  When we add the table again, will it re-add the relationship also?

Comment: Yes relationship also creates again.

Comment: `some changes` ... What kind of changes did you make?

Answer (score 0):

Open Sql database and then go to the Tools tab.In this tab choose option tab.
option windows open then click on designer tree-view in the tab table option appear
change in the check box in tab randomly than change database and save i think table will 
save after that.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to update the .edmx. I think following steps work:

1. Go inside the Model Browser
2. Delete the existing .edmx
3. Select Table/Views
4. Right click on Table/Views
5. Select Update Model From Database.
   And your .edmx will be updated.